# How to get access to +page.js data in +layout.svelte?

Tags: routes, return, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component

I am fetching from an endpoint within my `+page.js` file in a route in SvelteKit, and have verified that the data is being returned properly. When I return the data from `+page.js`, I can access it using `export let data` in `+page.svelte`, however the majority of where I need this data is in `+layout.svelte`.

Is there a way to access the data returned by `+page.js` within `+layout.svelte` in SvelteKit?

Comment: I think the correct way is to use a store and subscribe to this store in your layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass data from `+page.js` to `+layout.svelte`:

+page.js

```
export function load() {
  return {
    customData: "testingData",
  };
}
```

+layout.sevlte

```
<script>
  import { page } from "$app/stores";
</script>

{$page.data.customData}
```

[Docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#shared-state)